# Show image in popup Vaadin

Tags: image, popup, vaadin, vaadin7

I use Vaadin 7. I want to display a full sized image in a popup. The popup does not contain any close button nor resize. Just an image that takes full size in a popup. Does anyone done that before ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use standard PopupView with Content constructor.

```
PopupView c = new PopupView(new Content() {

        @Override
        public Component getPopupComponent() {
            return new Image("caption", resource); //use any resource
        }

        @Override
        public String getMinimizedValueAsHTML() {
            return "displayedstring";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by popup that does not contain any close or resize button?

You can use Vaadin's Window and disable the Close and Resize mechanism.

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.sub-window.html

Comment: Thanks @luuksen, but when you disable the close and Resize mechanism you still have the header of the subWindow. I said that I want to see the image and nothing else.

Comment: @Tantaoui El Mehdi You can hide the header using CSS.